# Is // or /-/ a valid URL component?

Tags: http, url

Background:  I'm creating a hierarchical geographic directory.  The geo databases I'm using has fields such that I can create a URL like this:
/ISO_country/1st_admin_division/2nd_admin_division/place_name/zipcode/

ISO_country, place_name, and zipcode are guaranteed to have data.  But 1st and 2nd admin division may or may not have data.

In US I have a /US/New-York/Nassau-County/Hicksville/51212/
But in South Africa I have /ZA/[blank]/[blank]/Pretoria/0030/

If I go with the (ugly) /ZA///Pretoria/0030/ is it a valid URL?  What about the also ugly /ZA/-/-/Pretoria/0030/?

Do any major browsers get "smart" and try to eliminate things like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are perfectly valid URIs. See [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

- [`/ZA///Pretoria/0030/`](http://ideone.com/6LJFb)
- [`/ZA/-/-/Pretoria/0030/`](http://ideone.com/kNZdy)

> Do any major browsers get "smart" and try to eliminate things like this?

Not as far as I've seen. BTW, dashes (`-`) are not special characters in URIs so you *really* don't need to concern yourself with those.

Answer (score 1):

Why not work on an optional-argument model? Both of these URLs seem workable and easily parseable:

```
/ZA/Pretoria/0030
/US/New-York/Nassau-County/Hicksville/51212/
```

And, just to throw a pickle in the works:

```
/AU/Victoria/Melbourne/3000
```

If you know that you'll always have values for your first, second-last and last items, why not  chomp the first one then parse your URL tokens backwards?

```
# rubyish pseudocode
tokens      = "/AU/Victoria/Melbourne/3000".split("/")
iso_country = tokens[0]

tokens.reverse!
tokens.drop_last_item!

zipcode          = tokens[0] # => 3000
place_name       = tokens[1] # => Melbourne
admin_division_2 = tokens[2] # => Victoria
admin_division_1 = tokens[3] # => nil / ""
```

Comment: I was initially going to go with an optional argument model.  But then I realized I had no way of knowing if ^/AU/Sometext/$ was /AU/admin1/ or /AU/place_name/

Comment: That's the reason for reversing your argument order—once you drop the first one, you already know the rest, just backwards.

Comment: Ah, now I see where you're going. This is written in django, so would have to drop into a view to do the parsing, but that's an elegant approach.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate—sorry it wasn't a direct answer to your question, then!

Comment: Not to be sorry at all.  The pseudo ruby is actually very close to real python that would be executed in the view function (django calls controllers views and views templates -- just to be difficult I think)